# java.lang.NullPointerException:attempt to invoke virtual 'void android.widget.TextView.setTest' on a null object refrence in android 2.1.3

Tags: android

it shows the error on the emulator while playing

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.nehagupta.braintrainer/com.nehagupta.braintrainer.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null
>   object reference  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2723)
>     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2784)
>     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1523)
>     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163)   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6238)     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)    at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:933)
>     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823)
>   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
>   method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)'
>   on a null object reference    at
>   com.nehagupta.braintrainer.MainActivity.generateQuestion(MainActivity.java:36)
>     at
>   com.nehagupta.braintrainer.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:90)
>     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6857)   at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
>     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2676)
>     ... 9 more
>
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.nehagupta.braintrainer/com.nehagupta.braintrainer.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null
>   object reference  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2723)
>     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2784)
>     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1523)
>     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163)   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6238)     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)    at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:933)
>     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823)
>   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
>   method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)'
>   on a null object reference    at
>   com.nehagupta.braintrainer.MainActivity.generateQuestion(MainActivity.java:36)
>     at
>   com.nehagupta.braintrainer.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:90)
>     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6857)   at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
>     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2676)
>     ... 9 more

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

I think that you must initialize your `TextView`.

If you are in activity, put below code in the `onCreate` method.

```
TextView myTextView = findViewById(R.id.your_text_view_id);
```

Or if you are in `Fragment`, then in `onCreateView` insert this line:

```
TextView myTextView = view.findViewById(R.id.text_view_id);
```

Comment: Error:(82, 48) error: cannot find symbol variable your_text_view_id

Comment: Man, you have to put same id that you set in `XML` file

Answer (score 0):

Check the view ID is same as you defined in the layout.xml file while initializing it in your context.